# Pyhton3.10 datetime strftime and isocalendar disagreement

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I believe that `strftime` is wrong in the example below. The year should be 2021. `isocalendar` is right.

```
Python 3.10.0 (v3.10.0:b494f5935c, Oct  4 2021, 14:59:20) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] on darwin
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date( 2022, 1, 1 ).strftime( '%Y-%V' )
'2022-52'
>>> datetime.date( 2022, 1, 1 ).isocalendar()
datetime.IsoCalendarDate(year=2021, week=52, weekday=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is the expected behaviour since you are using the `%Y` format specifier which will return the actual year of the date object.
However you want to use the `%G` format specifier to return the corresponding ISO year of the date, so try:

```
import datetime
datetime.date(2022, 1, 1).strftime('%G-%V')
# '2021-52'

Find out more from the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes
```